# What happens when separate wars with a common enemy end?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

Recently I started playing Hearts of Iron IV as Sweden.

Me and and the Soviet Union got into separate wars that had a common enemy (Norway). Norway managed to catch me by surprise and took over some of my land. That occupied land then got taken over by the Soviet Union.

What will happen to that territory once I or the Soviet Union ends the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any territory originally belonging to you will be returned to you, the soviets will not be able to take it.

Once Norway capitulates, the peace conference will star both you and the Soviets. You are then allowed to make demands from Norway depending on the amount of war score you got. The victor with the highest warscore gets to choose first, though. So, if you want to get anything out of it, try to capture Norways cities asap.